# How do I properly display a child block within it's parent in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, templates

I have the following:

**local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>

    <default>

        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="foo" as="foo" translate="label">
                <label>Foo</label>
            </block>
        </reference>

        <reference name="foo">
            <block type="core/template" name="fooblock" template="foo.phtml" />
        </reference>

        <reference name="bar">
            <block type="core/template" name="barblock" template="bar.phtml" />
        </reference>

        <reference name="foo">
            <action method="insert">
                <name>barblock</name>
            </action>
        </reference>

    </default>

</layout>
```

**foo.phtml**

```
<div>
<h1 style="background-color:yellow">Hello New Reference!</h1>
<div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?></div>
</div>
```

**bar.phtml**

```
<h1 style="background-color:yellow">Hello New Reference child!</h1>
```

**1column.phtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbsContainer') ?>
        <div class="main col1-layout">
            <div class="col-main">
                <h1>Custom package, Primary theme</h1>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('foo') ?>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this displays as the following (look near bottom of screenshot):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC9bf.png

How do I get the "child block" as listed in the screenshot to actually be a child block within the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `<reference name="bar">` but there is no block in your layout with the name "bar". You want to define "barblock" inside "fooblock":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>

    <default>

        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="foo" as="foo" translate="label">
                <label>Foo</label>
            </block>
        </reference>

        <reference name="foo">
            <block type="core/template" name="fooblock" template="foo.phtml" />
        </reference>

        <reference name="fooblock">
            <block type="core/template" name="barblock" template="bar.phtml" />
        </reference>

    </default>

</layout>
```

Comment: After making the changes you suggested it's working great, thanks. Magento layout is finally starting to make sense to me.